# Using AJAX to update a dynamic webpage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I made a webpage that consists of projects, where each project consists of a list of files. All of this information is acquired from a MySQL database. I've implemented a feature that allows users to comment on each file and reply to each other's comments. I have a php function called "place comments" which recursively places comments for each file shown below.

This is executed for every file and every file is displaced similarly using a while loop and some statements that echo html code.

However, the issue I'm having is using AJAX to post comments without the page refreshing. Since each file id is different, I would have to update every selector with a particular file id and run placeComments again for every file.

However I'm not sure how to accomplish this. I'm able to update my database through AJAX everytime I submit a comment.

I know you can do something like the following and it will update any selector with the id "id":

```
          $(document).ready(function() {  
             $.get('comments.php', function (data) {
                 $('#id').html(data);
             });
          });
```

But I'm not sure how I can do this iteratively for every file id where each file id is a php variable?
Is there a way I can communicate with JS through PHP so it updates comments
for all file ids? If so, how?

I realized that this is a terrible design, but I'd like to do this without starting my project from scratch.

Place comments function:

```
     function placeComments($mysqli, $parentId, $fileId) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE parent = $parentId AND file = $fileId ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) ASC";

            $comments = $mysqli->query($sql);
            while($comment = $comments->fetch_assoc())
            {
                echo '
                <ul class="comments">
                    <li class="clearfix">
                        <div class="post-comments">
                            <p class="meta"> '. $comment['date'] .' <a href="#">'. $comment['username'] .'</a> says : <i class="pull-right">
                            <p>'
                            .
                            $comment['content']
                            .

                            '</i></p><br><br>';

                echo '<div class = "col-sm-12 reply panel-group">';
                echo '<div class="panel panel-default">';
                echo '<p><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#'. $comment[
                    'file'] . '-' . $comment['id'] . '"> Reply </a></p>';
                echo '<div id="'. $comment['file'] . '-' . $comment['id'] .'" class="panel-collapse collapse">';
                echo '<div class="panel-body">';


                if(isset($_POST['submitComment-' . $comment['file'] . '-' . $comment['id']]))
                {
                    $user = $_POST['username'];
                    $content = $_POST['content'];
                    $fileId = $_POST['id'];
                    $parent = $_POST['parent'];
                    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());

                    filterComment($mysqli, $fileId, $user, $parent, $content, $date);
                }   

                echo '<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="commentForm" role="form"> 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-10 form">
                        <h5><b> Name: <b></h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10 form">
                          <textarea class="form-control" name="username" id="username" rows="1"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10 form">
                        <h5><b> Reply: <b></h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10 form">
                          <textarea class="form-control" name="content" id="content" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input class = "form-control" type = "hidden" value = '. $comment['file'] . ' name = "id" id = "id" />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input class = "form-control" type = "hidden" value = '. $comment['id'] . ' name = "parent" id = "parent" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10 form">                    
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-circle text-uppercase" type="submit" id="submitComment" name = "submitComment-'. $comment['file'] .'-' . $comment['id'] . '"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span> Reply </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>            
                </form>';

                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div><br><br>';
                placeComments($mysqli, $comment['id'], $comment['file']);
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</li>';



                echo '</ul>';
            }

            $comments->free();


        }
```

Comment: I will be honest with you. I didn't understand what you want to accomplish.

Comment: As per my understanding, wherever you want to show the comments, call this ajax functionality. So put your ajax functionality inside a function, & call this function, in every file where you want to show the comments.

Comment: @reenleedr , assume I have a php file that dynamically creates a list of files on a webpage by echoing html code. I want users to be able to comment on every file, asynchronously using AJAX to update the comments. However I don't know how to do this if I have potentially thousands of files with different html ids.

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu, there are potentially over thousands of files. How would I accomplish something like this without writing ajax code over and over again? The thing is: each of my files has a different id. But I'm not sure how to let AJAX know which file id to update. I essentially want to "send" some info about files to AJAX from PHP. But I'm not sure how I can do that